# Total unimodularity and the set of optimizers

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Suppose I have a totally unimodular matrix $A$ and an integral vector $b$. Consider for a vector $c$ the following linear program:
$$
\max_x c^Tx \quad s.t.\quad Ax\le b
$$
Let $S$ be the set of maximizers and let $S_{int} \subseteq S$ be the subset of integer-valued maximizers. Then is it true that $S = \mathrm{conv}(S_{int})$, i.e., $S$ is the convex hull of $S_{int}$?

Comment: I would like to say that (assuming the polyhedron defined by $Ax\leqslant b$ is bounded) an optimal solution to the LP is a convex combination of vertices at which the optimal value is attained, from which this claim follows readily. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: Thank you. In my application, $\{x: Ax \le b\}$  is unbounded but the set of optimizers are bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Minkowski representation theorem, every point in your feasible set is the sum of a convex combination of extreme points and a nonnegative combination of extreme directions. Every extreme point corresponds to at least one basic feasible solution (possibly more than one if the point is degenerate), and $A$ being TUM and $b$ being integer-valued means that every BFS (and so every extreme point) is integer-valued.

So it comes down to the extreme rays.

- If the feasible set is bounded (no feasible rays), your answer is yes.
- If it is unbounded but the objective function is *strictly decreasing* along *every* extreme ray, then your answer is yes, because the Minkowski representation of every optimal solution will necessarily have zero coefficients for every extreme ray.
- If it is unbounded and the objective increases along *any* extreme ray, the problem is unbounded and the question is meaningless (there are no optima).
- Finally, if the feasible region is unbounded, the objective function is *nonincreasing* along all extreme rays but *constant along at least one*, then the answer is no, because any optimal extreme point will anchor a ray of optimal solutions.